# What is the best way to initialise the state of a react component while using SSR?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, server-side-rendering, react-state-management

I'm building a table which state needs to be initialised somewhere and which data is eventually updated via fetch.

My problem is that table needs to be serverside rendered and therefor the data needs to be rendered on the server before the component is mounted, I can't use componentDidMount.

I can render the table inners in the render() method using props but then how can I update the data later on when the table doesn't rely on receiving data via props but via calls to an api?

My conclusion was I have to use state but initialising state with props seems to be a big no no so I'm in a dilemna.

What's your advice on initialing state of the compnent without breaking that rule?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but most times people just downvote things that have no code or when your question is not very clear. I am going to try to answer it the way it is because I believe I understand what you're trying to accomplish and how you could get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

**You can initialize state using props. There will be no issue in that.**

My approach will be:

- Keep one state variable and initialize it with props to render it on server side.
- As the component is mounted on client-side, API will be called in componentDidMount.
- Any new props changes will be monitored in componentWillReceiveProps
  or static getDerivedStateFromProps (depending on your react version). If any new data comes, update the redux-store (if you are using redux-store) or update the component state to cause the re-rendering to show the updated data.

Example boiler plate:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tableData: props.tableData
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Make API call here
    callAPItoGetData()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { tableData } =  nextProps
    if(tableData !== this.state.tableData ) { 
      //You need to make sure that this condition is fullfiled only once to avoid setting state multiple times
      this.setState({
        tableData: nextProps.tableData
      })
      //Alternatively, an action can be dispatched to update the redux-store which will update the props and cause re-render with new data
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{/*render table here*/}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good case for [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), and the useEffect hook. According to the docs:

> you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

Here is a simple example where the component has the prop data as the state at first, but once the API call is completed, it changes to the API data:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function DataList(props) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(props.propData);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setUsers(data);
      });
  });
  return (
    <ul>
      {users.map((user, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{user.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default DataList;
```

Answer (score 1):

My take here: 
Let your component mount an empty table by initializing state with default values and add to your component a function that fetches from where you're saying the data should come from. Get this function to be called when an event that makes sense to your app happens.

Let me know if and why that wouldn't work, and what other problems you run into.